# Как срабатывает этот код?

Tags: javascript

```
!function __last(){
    console.log(123)
}();
```

Я так понимаю, после фигурной скобки закрывающей - идет вызов функции, а что означает, и как работает восклицательный знак перед *function*?

Comment: @Igor, не, это чтобы сделать из function declaration - function expression

Comment: http://bolknote.ru/2012/04/23/~3642 почитайте, тут всё понятно написано

Answer (score 0):

Когда мы функцию оборачиваем в скобки то мы обозначаем интерпретатору, что это выражение

```
(function __last() {
    console.log(123)
})();
```

ваш код также является выражением, но вы обозначаете 
это с помощью унарного оператора отрицания(восклицательный знак).

И после выполняется операция вызова т.е. () для вашего выражения.